# Django - Render to Response

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am using the following code in my Django view

```
data = {'d':['a','b','c']}
return render_to_response('login/invalid.html',data)
```

Now i want my `invalid.html` page to have the code to convert the list `['a','b','c']` to a javascript variable array so that i can populate a dropdown menu. But i cannot convert these elements into a javascript array.

```
var arr = "{{ 'd' }}"
```

takes the list as a string and not as an array
Please help

---

This code creates a drop down using an array

```
<select >
              <script type="text/javascript">

              {% autoescape off %}
              var veg = {{ d }}
              {% endautoescape %}

                 for (i = 0; i < veg.length; i++) {
                     document.write('<option>')
                     document.write(veg[i])                   
                     document.write('</option>')                    
                }
             </script>            
         </select>
```

---

```
                d = json.dumps(['a','b','c'])
                #d = serializers.serialize("json", ['a','b','c'])
                #data={"d":json.dumps(['1','2','3','4'])}
                #data={}
                data = {'d':d}

                #data["read"] = json.dumps(",".join(['abc']))

                #return render_to_response('login/invalid.html',json.dumps(data),context_instance=RequestContext(request))

                return render_to_response('login/invalid.html',data,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to [serialize your data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#serializing-django-objects) as json:

```
import json

d = json.dumps(['a','b','c']) 
# now d actually has a json string
data = {'d':d}
return render_to_response('login/invalid.html',data)
```

Then in your template

```
// arr now holds the list
{% autoescape off %}
var arr = {{ d }}
{% endautoescape %}
console.log(arr);
arr.doSomething();
```

Comment: oops, corrected. You can just use json for simple data types that aren't django models.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the list into JSON via `json` and output it in the template, marking it safe as required.

Comment: data = {'d':['a','b','c']} ....
j = json.dumps(data) ...


After using j in render to response
How do i access it in the javascript code?

Comment: You want to encode the list, not the dictionary. `data = {'d': json.dumps(...)}` ... `var arr = {{ d }}`

Comment: I have posted the code to generate the drop down..but when i use veg = {{d}} it does not work

Comment: The list contains simple ['a','b','c'] just to create a drop down menu

Comment: That's nice. **Show us what the bleeping document contains.**

Comment: Sorry..I just added the complete snippets

Comment: And when you view the source?